# French visa reapplication after refusal?

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, filipino-citizens

Is it advisable to reapply to the French Embassy for Schengen visa after refusal? I got my refusal two days ago, for these reasons:

8. The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and the conditions of the intended stay was not reliable
9. Your intention to leave the territory of the Member State before the expiry of the visa cannot be ascertained

I am a Philippine passport holder and work as a freelance video editor with clients locally and a main one from Australia. Is it possible to reapply immediately?

Comment: Yes, you can re-apply but what has substantially changed? Did you forget to include some documents?

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can reapply immediately, but it is probably not a good idea.

**The French officials believe that you might try to immigrate illegally.**

You have to convince them that you are a *real* tourist or business traveler (item 8) who does want to return to the Philippines after the trip (item 9). The French authorities want visitors to come, but they also want to be certain that the applicant is a visitor.

- As a business traveler, you need to explain what you want to do in France and that you fit the profile of an employee who would be *sent* to France (a major business expense) and who would return to work in the Philippines. *As a freelancer you are your own employee, but the same principle applies.*
- As a tourist, you need to explain that you fit the profile of somebody who will spend thousands of Euros on a *luxury expense* and who would return to live in the Philippines afterwards. That means a good, steady, and well-documented income, and ties to the local economy/society.

If you submitted all those documents, and they were not enough, then the next application won't have a different outcome. This is not a lottery, they have rules and procedures, and similar applications get similar answers.

Comment: Aside from complying to all the documents on the checklist, I would like to add the following: 
-Contract to sell of the condominium property under my name
- Vehicle deed of sale I haven't had it transferred yet
-Life insurances
-I will request for a certification that I have an ongoing project until January

The proof as a tourist is what I am confused. I have submitted my old passport with stamps from other SE asian countries, a very detailed itinerary in schengen,bank certificate and statements. I am thinking of adding credit card statements as well. What else can I possibly attach?

Comment: None of those will make much difference. At a guess: your income is too low or too unstable to convince them you'd spend a lot of money on a holiday

Comment: I believe my bank certificate and statements can prove that I have the means to support my travel. On my IT, I requested for 24 Days which includes the following cities: Paris, Amsterdam, Berlin, Prague, Budapest, Rome and Italy. Will it be rather suspicious if I change my plan to 14 days only and Paris - Rome - Milan only?